# Composer run time (0.19.4) is not compatible with client (0.19.2) trying to downgrade or upgrade

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i have 
uninstall/install the composer

> npm uninstall -g composer-cli
>
> npm install -g composer-cli

and i have run

> teardownFabric.sh
>
> go the the following error .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
>   or directory: '/cygdrive/c/Users/Hiii
>   /workspace/HLF-Windows-Fabric-Tool/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/docker-compose.yml

**is there any simple way just ugrade or downgrade and make both in the same sync**

Answer (score 1):

updated with specify the version using the command:

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.4 (it solved  me the error)
```